# How can I use "dot syntax" inside of jade

Tags: pug

I create some basic jade file:

```
doctype
html
  body.
   <div>blah blah</div>
   <div>blah blah</div>
   .container
```

but jade do not see .container as div. I know I can use pipe syntax but what if i want to use dot?

Is there any way to cancel dot?

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Tag Interpolation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/) and everything inside it is assumed to be plain HTML. `#[]` is then used to insert Jade.

Instead, you could just use plain HTML directly

```
.body
    <div>blah blah</div>
    <div>blah blah</div>
    .container
        <div>This is inside the .container class div</div>
```

will render

```
<div class="body">
    <div>blah blah</div>
    <div>blah blah</div>
    <div class="container"><div>This is inside the .container class div</div></div>
</div>
```